# Silverlight from database to datagrid

Tags: database, silverlight, datagrid, schema

I'm looking for a schema or a tutorial that would explain the different steps to go from the database to the datagrid.

Something like "Database" -> "Entity(edmx)" -> "Service(Server)" -> "Service(client)" -> "Datagrid".

Or anything I may have missed about the Silverlight model, like most used methods, etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is:

`"Database" -> "Entity(edmx)" -> "RIA Services(Server)" -> "RIA Service(client domain context)" -> "Datagrid"`

RIA Services takes care of most of the to-and-fro of data and you can bind directly to the domain context using drag-drop etc in the Visual Studio editors.

[Try this page for starters](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/advanced-techniques/wcf-ria-services/using-wcf-ria-services)